# What does this C++ statement mean? BaseWindow() : m_hwnd(NULL) { }

Tags: c++

I am going through the "Getting started with the Windows API" portion of MSDN, and ran into an aspect of C++ I'm having trouble understanding.

I've been looking in "The C++ Programming Language" by Stroustrup, and can't find this particular thing.

Please check the link to the relevant [page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381400.aspx).

The line that I don't understand is:

```
BaseWindow() : m_hwnd(NULL) { }
```

This line is in the latter code snippet describing an object oriented approach to the subject. `m_hwnd` is of the type `HWND`.

I really have no idea what is happening here. I'm pretty sure it's a constructor that doesn't do much of anything, but this specific syntax is foreign to me. I must admit my C++ knowledge is mostly just "C with some C++ stuff added". I'm currently diving deep into Stroustrup to remedy that.

Comment: The book you're reading *should* explain it. Perhaps if you knew the right term for it, it would be easier to find? The correct term is *constructor initializer list*.

Comment: Ok, I found the relevant portion of the book. That seems to have given me clarity. You're right, my lack of the term I needed to search was my main difficulty. Tell me if I have this right. A class derived from BaseWindow gets its m_hwnd member set to NULL upon object instantiation. Is that right? The colon is still fuzzy to me here.

Comment: Dan Moos - that is right, I think this is part of derived class.

Comment: Dan Moos - that is right, I think this is part of derived class.

BaseWindow() - this calls the BaseWindow default constructor (BaseWindow might have other constructors). The colon says the base class constructors calls are over.
m_hwnd(NULL) - this is doing derived member initialisation
{ } - main body of derived constructor, empty, all base classes and members initialised by this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colon is just a syntax divider between the constructor declaration and the [constructor initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

It's a way to directly construct (or initialize) member variables.

It's similar (but *not equal*) to

```
BaseWindow()
{
    m_hwnd = NULL;
}
```

---

Another way to look at it: Lets say you define a normal local variable, and want to initialize it to a specific value. There are a couple of ways to doing it.

1. Definition (with [*default initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization)) and assignment:

   ```
   HWND hwnd;
   hwnd = 0;
   ```
2. Definition and [*copy initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization):

   ```
   HWND hwnd = 0;
   ```
3. Definition and [*direct initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization):

   ```
   HWND hwnd(0);
   ```

With a constructor initializer list, you use *direct initialization* in the constructor, and it happens *before* the constructor function body is executed.

Note that templates doesn't play any part of this. And neither does inheritance, even though it's possible to "call" a parent class constructor using a constructor initializer list.

Lastly an important note: Constructor initializer lists should not be confused with [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

Comment: Its perfectly clear now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> `BaseWindow() : m_hwnd(NULL) { }`

That declares a default constructor for `BaseWindow`, which initializes the `m_hwnd` with a `NULL` value.

It does *not*, however, guarantee that `m_hwnd` will always be initialized to `NULL`.  For instance, the default copy constructor will not do that.  An explicit copy constructor is not likely to do it, either.